# On refresh brower's Data is getting inserted -- Help!

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have insert page - data is getting inserted properly with all validations .But the main problem is that after insert if anyone clicks on the refresh button on the Internet explorer browser , data gets inserted again the same data which insert on submit button .

Thanks,
Smartdev

Comment: could plz explain it in a little detail? may be along with posting some of your code (.aspx and backend)

Comment: Its a simple insert code with ...with five textboxes and drop downs , once user clicks the submit button the data is inserted and im clearing the text boxes for user to enter data again.but once data is inserted and textboxes are cleared ,if users clicks refresh on browser the data is inserted again in database .this the same data which inserted by user ,when i check my database it shows the same data with time difference of seconds . 

I dnt have any code - its just insert method with stored procedure and parameters im passing from code behind.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do a redirect after you successfully perform the insert and this should not happen. Otherwise, you'll have to perform some process yourself to make sure it doesn't happen (perhaps use state management to set a "Has been saved" flag or something).

Comment: Hi David, 
I cant do tht cause im clearing the textboxes aftersubmit for another entry . is there any other method
Thanks,
Smartdev

Answer (score 0):

A redirect would work. You can use something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(dataWasInserted)
        Response.Redirect("~/TheSamePage.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Hi Chess ,

I cant do tht cause im clearing the textboxes aftersubmit for another entry . is there any other method

Comment: See my other answer, adding logic to your stored procedure.

Answer (score 0):

You can add code to your stored procedure that checks the database before the insert. If the data already exists that you are trying to avoid, do not execute the insert.

If you really want to allow intentional repetition of data, but not via accidental refreshes, you can use your timestamp to help determine if it was a recent duplicate that you want to block. Hopefully, though, you don't want duplicate data in your database at all, so I don't recommend that approach.

Answer (score 0):

Dear User u have to use below code in the previous page to avoid back button work.

```
example...

suppose your page 1 is=x.jsp  and page 2 is y.jsp

to restrict x.jsp when u click on y.jsp back button you have to add this code in x.jsp

<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noBack() { window.history.forward(); }
</SCRIPT>
</HEAD>
<BODY onload="noBack();"
    onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```